# Update data in infinity list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have component - items list with infinity scrolling. When it scrolled down and add elements to list it not fill them with recived data (array with new data recived, but new added elements is empty)

May be I need to update em somehow? Its the same component and it update list when it add new element, why it not update data in new elements? All needed data also in recived array.

```
const MyItemsList: React.FC<ItemsListProps> = (props) => {
  const [size, setSize] = useState(5)
  const [type, setType] = useState('ALL')

  const observer = useRef<IntersectionObserver>()
  const { isLoading, content, hasMore } = useGetContent(size, type)

  const lastItemRef = useCallback((node) => {
    if (isLoading) return
    if (observer.current) observer.current.disconnect() 
    
    observer.current = new IntersectionObserver(entries => { 
      if (entries[0].isIntersecting && hasMore) {
        setSize(prevSize => prevSize + 1)
      }
    })
    if (node) observer.current.observe(node) 
  }, [isLoading, hasMore])

  const itemsList = () => {
    if (typeof (content) !== 'undefined') {
      return content.map((item, index) => {
        if (content.length === index + 1) {
          return (
            <li key={item.id} ref={lastItemRef}>
              <ItemPreview item={item} />
            </li>
          )
        }

        return (
          <li key={item.id}>
            <ItemPreview item={item} />
          </li>
        )

      })
    }
    return ( <div>Loading...</div> )
  }
  return ( <ul>{itemsList()}</ul> )
}

export default MyItemsList
```

< ItemPreview />

```
interface ItemProps {
  item: {
    id: number,
    title: string,
    text: string,
  },
}

const ItemPreview: React.FC<ItemProps> = (props) => {
  const { item } = props;
  return (
    <>
      <div>{item.title}</div>
      <div>{item.text}</div>
    </>
  )
}

export default ItemPreview
```

Any advice how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your itemList into a hook like shown below

```
  const itemsList = useMemo(() => {
    if (typeof (content) !== 'undefined') {
      return content.map((item, index) => {
        if (content.length === index + 1) {
          return (
            <li key={item.id} ref={lastItemRef}>
              <ItemPreview item={item} />
            </li>
          )
        }

        return (
          <li key={item.id}>
            <ItemPreview item={item} />
          </li>
        )

      })
    }
    return []
  }, [content, lastItemRef])
```

and then instead of calling itemList(), just use itemList
and to show loading add a check like this before rendering itemList

```
if !itemList.length {
  return ( <div>Loading...</div> )
}
```

Comment: tried it and it gave me the same result - all new added elements have no data, :(

Comment: have u checked if the itemList's new data has title and text by printing the list on the console ?

Comment: oh, thats strange... I checked console.log. add it after ```return content.map((item, index) => {if (content.length === index + 1) {```  like this ```console.log('content', content, 'item', item)```  when it render first time content has array and item has item from this array. but after scrolling when added new element content is array and item is the same array with all elements. (((

Comment: ty! found error in other file. tried to render wrong formed array. your code works well, and my code in question works well. it was just bad array.